# Using 'which' command in cron job

Tags: bash, path, ffmpeg

I have a cron job that runs once a day on a Linux server and in the script it executes there is a test:

```
# Validate ffmpeg is installed
if [ $(which ffmpeg | grep -c "ffmpeg") -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "error: ffmpeg is not installed!" | tee -a "$log"
    exit 1
fi
```

Every day when I check the logfile, the message `ffmpeg is not installed!` is in the log and as result the work has not been executed. If I run the `which` test in the shell everything works fine and when I execute the script everything works.

Is there something intrinsic to cron that prevents it from being able to properly use the `which` command?

Comment: Why not just use `[ -x /path/to/ffmpeg ] ...` to check it exists and is executable ? http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: What would be the point of the test if you already know that ffmpeg is installed and its installation path? This test ensures that users don't try to run the program on a server which doesn't have ffmpeg installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the top of your crontab file put SHELL and PATH declaration like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

See [this SE post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths#)  for more details.

The default SHELL and PATH for cron are `SHELL=/bin/sh`, `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` (From `man 5 crontab` man page).

Answer (score 6):

It probably does not pick up your path since it's running from cron. There are several ways to make it know the path the easiest I have found is just hard code the path to which.

Do a:

```
locate which
```

Mine returns this:

```
[user@server ~]$ locate which |grep bin
/usr/bin/which
```

Then change your script to do:

```
if [ $(/usr/bin/which ffmpeg | grep -c "ffmpeg") -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "error: ffmpeg is not installed!" | tee -a "$log"
    exit 1
fi
```

Another option is to set the environment and path in the crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: You could also use the rather humorous `which which`.